# Pass json from ajax to laravel controller

Tags: json, laravel

would you like to help me? I have an ajax like this

```
var id = {{@$projectid}};
var datatab = JSON.stringify({data: change})
$.ajax({
  url: 'save/'+id,
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'JSON',
  data: {json:datatab},
  success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
});
```

and then, I want to pass the datatab as json to database in json field
this is my save function in controller

```
 public function save($project_id=0, Request $request)
 {
    $project_id = $request->project_id;
    $weight = $request->weight;

    TaskPlanning::create([
        'project_id' => $project_id,
        'weight' => $weight
    ]);

    return response()->json([]);
}
```

In database, weight field is json. and I want to save my json file from ajax to weight
This is my model

```
class TaskPlanning extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'p_task_planning';
    protected $fillable = ['project_id','weight'];

    public function project()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Project::class,'project_id','id');
    }

    public function milestone()
   {
       return $this->belongsTo(Milestone::class,'milestone_id','id');
   }

   protected $casts = [
      'weight' => 'array'
   ];
 }
```

Comment: what problem or error ur facing?

Comment: no, I don't get error. But I don't know how to passing json data to laravel controller.

Comment: u havent included csrf_token itself check i have updated the code below.

Comment: Who do you stringify 'change'? What's in it? The request helper does auto detect JSON and will give you an array. Try `dd($request->all());` and see what you get. Also, it's better to get requested data as `$project_id = $request->get('project_id');` to avoid unnecessary errors.

Comment: I use stringify 'change' because I using handsontable and when the table was changed, I want to save the all data in table as a json and retrieve a project_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
var id = {{@$projectid}};
var datatab = JSON.stringify({data: 'change'});
$.ajax({
  url: 'save/'+id,
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'JSON',
   data: {_token   : '{!! csrf_token() !!}',
          weight   : datatab,
          project_id : id 
         },
  success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use **`axios`** instead of $.ajax..

just make sure you add meta tag

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" >
```

then

use axios like this..it will auto load csrf token

```
axios.post('save/'+id, data).then(function (response) {
    //response
});
```